# Linux Bash Script Ideas

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have been given the task of creating a shell script to show my proficiency in scripting. I am really struggling with ideas on what to do. I would like to create something that is relevant and could be useful.

During my time on the course I have covered:

- Threads, concunrency and locking.
- File systems.
- Virtual Machines.
- Networking.
- Security tools like tiger.

I haven't had the experince of programming a lot in shell scripts but I have experince in other programming languages so I understand the flow and logic of how to program I would just need to check up on the syntax.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a script to transfer files directly between 2 remote machines that have fast internet acess without going through the local host, as if the user of this script is SSH'd to the 2 remote hosts via a slow old dialup connection.  **and, of course, do the file transfer securely**.

the way i did it is:

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ka9wgn/scripts/tarnet

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ka9wgn/scripts/cpionet

Comment: compressing the transfer would be a nice plus.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have done something similar where I had two virtual machines, one server, one debian machine. The debian machine would boot up and ssh into the server, take a script file which contained installation instructions and execute the script all during the boot sequence. Apologize that and 1 other scripts are ones I have already completed. I should of mentioned above.

Comment: doing it via ssh would mean the server side needs to be configured to accept ssh connections from the client. does your script set this up securely? does it use passwords or keys?

Comment: Yeah the connection was fully secured both ways. Keys were used.

Comment: how did the script get the server to authorize that client's key?  keys built into the script?

Comment: Apologizes it was FTP not ssh. I did have ssh built in on the machines but it was a basic openssh setup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21853/discussion-between-skaperen-and-softey).